# Equivalent activerecord query in rails for datetime range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Can anyone help me for writing a equivalent code in Rails 4.0 for the below sql

SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE (‘2008-12-21 00:00:00' BETWEEN ‘rooms.fromtime’ AND ‘rooms.totime’)

Basically i have a model called Room and i have two datetime columns like fromtime and totime in all the rows now for any time (from view) that is going to be entered newly must be compared with the range of fromtime and totime in all the rows and if it is falling in the range of any rows it should through a message to the user and should not allow to proceed. Any info regarding this will really help.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to grab the times from the view you'll have to pass params to a controller and then find the rooms:

```
to = params[:to_time]
from = params[:from_time]

Room.where("fromtime <= ? AND totime >= ?", from, to)
```

Replace the timestamps in the example with whatever times you need to check.

Comment: thanks nick.. but i need to get the from and to from view it can be selected from the user

Comment: Cool. I updated the answer. Basically, you just have to pass the params to whatever controller you're using to accept the user input.

Comment: thanks a lot nick.. but here i think it is only checking the time > and < not the range.. in my case for eg: if the fromtime and totime data in some rows  is 2015-08-15 13:00:00 and 2015-08-15 14:00:00.. then if the user gives 2015-08-15 13:30:00 in the view next time it should not allow to.. ie it should check this particular condition.. can u pls help for this..